# How to deserialize an OpenAPI 3 YAML file with a polymorphic array based on a discriminator in Golang?

Tags: go, openapi

I would like to deserialize some `YAML` data in `Golang` based on an `OpenApi 3` schema. The specification contains a `polymorphic array`. How can it be deserialized to the corresponding struct types in Golang based on a `discriminator` type? I tried to use an interface as a base type in the Traits array, but then I'm not able to `upcast` the individual items with an explicit cast. Is this an issue of the [go-yaml](https://github.com/goccy/go-yaml) library I'm using or in the structure of my structs / interface types?

Here is my crude attempt:

```golang
import (
  "fmt"
  "github.com/goccy/go-yaml"
  //"gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

func main() {
    discriminators()
}

func discriminators() {
    var yamlData = `
spec:
  traits:
    - name: Web dashboard
      type: ui
      summary: hmmm ET
    - name: Wiki
      type: documentation
      description: Description
`
    data := Data{}

    if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlData), &data); err == nil {

        trait := data.Spec.Traits[0]

        //type=ui
        uiTrait := trait.(UiTrait)

        println(uiTrait.Description)
    }
}

type TraitInterface interface {
    getName() string //`yaml:"name"`
}

type Trait struct {
    Name  string `yaml:"name"`
    Type_ string `yaml:"type"`
}

type UiTrait struct {
    //Trait Trait `json:"trait"`

    Name  string `yaml:"name"`
    Type_ string `yaml:"type"`

    Description string `json:"description,omitempty"`
}

type DocumentationTrait struct {
    //Trait Trait `json:"trait"`

    Name  string `yaml:"name"`
    Type_ string `yaml:"type"`

    Summary string `json:"summary,omitempty"`
}

type Specification struct {
    Traits []interface{} `yaml:"traits,omitempty"`
    //Traits []TraitInterface `yaml:"traits,omitempty"`
}

type Data struct {
    Spec Specification `yaml:"spec"`
}

func (a UiTrait) getName() string {

    return a.Name
}
```

OpenApi 3 specification with `oneOf`:

```yaml
openapi: "3.0.0"

components:

  schemas:

    Specification:
      type: object
      additionalProperties: false
      properties:
        traits:
          type: array
          items:
            oneOf:
            - $ref: "#/components/schemas/UiTrait"
            - $ref: "#/components/schemas/DocumentationTrait"
            discriminator: 
              propertyName: type
              mapping:
                ui: "#/components/schemas/UiTrait"
                documentation: "#/components/schemas/DocumentationTrait"  

    Trait:
      type: object
      additionalProperties: false
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        type:
          description: Type of trait
          type: string
        description:
          description: Description
          type: string
      required:
      - name
      - type

    DocumentationTrait:
      allOf:
      - $ref: "#/components/schemas/Trait"
      - type: object
        additionalProperties: false
        properties:
          summary:
            type: string

    UiTrait:
      allOf:
      - $ref: "#/components/schemas/Trait"
      - type: object
        additionalProperties: false
        properties:
          description:
            type: string
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look to https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen . you'll be able to generate code from you swagger yml file and solve your issues, without writing code

Comment: I originally tried to generate the code with swagger (https://editor.swagger.io/), but it didn't work well. I will try to use oapi-codegen. Thx.

Comment: @J-JacquesM I tried out oapi-codegen. It doesn't support 'OneOf' (https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen#whats-missing-or-incomplete) at the moment, but it is good as a starting point. Thx!

Comment: It support use 'allOf' instead like:

```mainObject:
    type: object
    allOf:
      - $ref: 'schemas.yaml#/nestedObject1'
      - $ref: 'schemas.yaml#/nestedObject2'
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of the items is map[string] interface{}, that's why the type assertion fails. It's not a conversion. It just checks (asserts) if the interface is actually that type. See https://go.dev/tour/methods/15.

I am suggesting to use [mapstructure](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) which has been created with this usecase in mind.

> Perhaps we can't populate a specific structure without first reading the "type" field from the JSON. We could always do two passes over the decoding of the JSON (reading the "type" first, and the rest later). However, it is much simpler to just decode this into a map[string]interface{} structure, read the "type" key, then use something like this library to decode it into the proper structure.

Also note that you have a bug in your types. The UI type has a summary and the documentation type as a description, but in your code it's switched around.

```
func discriminators() {
    var yamlData = `
spec:
  traits:
    - name: Web dashboard
      type: ui
      summary: hmmm ET
    - name: Wiki
      type: documentation
      description: Description
`
    data := Data{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlData), &data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    trait := data.Spec.Traits[0]
    var ut UiTrait
    if err := mapstructure.Decode(trait, &ut); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    println(ut.Summary)

}

type Data struct {
    Spec Specification `yaml:"spec"`
}

type Trait struct {
    Name  string `yaml:"name"`
    Type_ string `yaml:"type"`
}

type UiTrait struct {
    Name    string `yaml:"name"`
    Type_   string `yaml:"type"`
    Summary string `json:"summary,omitempty"`
}

type DocumentationTrait struct {
    Name        string `yaml:"name"`
    Type_       string `yaml:"type"`
    Description string `json:"description,omitempty"`
}

type Specification struct {
    Traits []interface{} `yaml:"traits,omitempty"`
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/ZjrEzn6jEYQ

Comment: Very nice @The Fool ! Sorry for the bug in the example.

Comment: Is this a correct way to use the discriminator? `m, ok := trait.(map[string]interface{})

 if ok {
  traitType := m["type"]

  switch traitType {
  case "ui":
   var ut UiTrait
   if err := mapstructure.Decode(trait, &ut); err != nil {
    panic(err)
   }
   println(ut.Summary)
  case "documentation":
   //
  }
 }`

Comment: Sorry I don't know ho to format the code within a comment

Comment: @Kubus, You don't need to type assert the trait.  You can make your trait field in the spec instead `[]map[string]interface{}`